# Facebook app not showing on "Insights for your website"

Tags: facebook

I have a website for which I created an App and a like button.

I want to link it with my https://www.facebook.com/insights, but when I click on "Insights for your website", I only get to link it with my own user account, and another app I've created previously.

The new app I had just created is not showing.

On my website, I added all OG tags, including the app_id tag. I did not include my own admin id, for I don't want people to find out my user account.

So why isn't my new app showing when I click on "Insights for your website"??